# Eclipse IDE not working

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

My Eclipse IDE was working fine till yesterday but when I downloaded HAXM in extras I don't know what happen to my Eclipse IDE. its not working now. When I start eclipse it shows that Android SDK content Loader (0%) and after one hour it still in 0 percent its not progressing. i try many times but same result. I have closed eclise and tried again but no result. I have restarted my system and tried again but IDE is still not working and showing "Android SDK content Loader (0%)"

Please help me to solve this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of a handful of reasons why its not loading. Quickest solution to this is to uninstall your IDE and re-install it with the latest SDK. Be sure to save your projects and reload them after you install Eclipse.

Comment: I un-install Eclipse and delete all its files. After that i again download and extract it..and the problem is solved Thanks!!...:)

Answer (score 0):

Which Eclipse you are using? If you are using older version, please find a newer version. I don't know how HAXM creates this problem. As treesandlake has said, you can do that also. But I think you need a updated Eclipse.

Comment: I am using Eclipse juno. i have latest version.

Comment: Ok then uninstall this eclipse or remove the eclipse folder and install/extract the eclipse again. Import `ADT Plugin` directly from web. Let's see the result.